# MemoryStream threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: memorystream, c#-8.0

No matter what, new instances of `MemoryStream` in C# / .NET 8.0 keep throwing this exception:

```
CanRead [bool]: true
CanSeek [bool]: true
CanTimeout [bool]: false
CanWrite [bool]: true
Capacity [int]: 1000
Length [long]: 1000
Position [long]: 0
ReadTimeout [int]:
'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
WriteTimeout [int]:
'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
```

**Here is the code that is being used that results in this error. Note that this code works successfully in .NET 4.6+ so why is it not working in .NET 8?**

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[1000];       
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(myBytes))
{
   var foobar = ms; // exception thrown here
}
```

Comment: That is not an exception that crashed your program.  You'd see this in the debugger when looking at a MemoryStream object.  It dutifully displays all properties, without knowing that timeouts have no meaningful implementation on a memory stream.  Doesn't make sense, it takes no time to read or write from/to a memory stream.  Keep going, you don't have a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

By adding these lines **before** writing to the stream, I was able to resolve this issue:

```
ms.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57082384/327066